# Parse push notifications appear on Parse.com's Push Notif table but not on actual device

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification, parse-platform

I've managed to send push notifications to specific users, as in my message appears on the Push Notification table on Parse.com, with a segmented target and 1 subscriber. The problem is, the person I'm sending the message to does not seem to receive the push notif, as in their badge number didn't increase (that was part of the push's data) and they didn't have the notification message pop up at the top of their phone screen. What I should do to have these things happen when I send them a push notification?

I'm using iOS by the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a variety of things before this can even happen. Are you sure you're using the correct push notification certificate for the app deployment being tested (dev cert for building out via debug, prod cert for adhoc builds). Did you configure the proper parse keys and follow their quick start guide for implementing push notifications? Are you connected to the internet on the device? If the badge count key in the json for the push notification is set, and the badge icon is not changing on the application, the device isn't getting the push notification period. Which means either the cert is wrong, or the app isn't properly registering for the push notifications.